# Return list of saved items using populate() in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, ejs

I am trying to create a page displaying saved items per user, so far my view is showing the JSON string, I want to render the original document (image, title, date,..)
Trying to understand populate() better.
Thanks

**In DB**

```
  {
    "_id":{"$oid":"6089d131efbe7e3e0c5c51f3"},
    "joinDate":{"$date":"2021-04-28T21:17:06.928Z"},
    "name":"...",
    "email":"...",
    "password":"...",
    "createdAt":{"$date":"2021-04-28T21:18:41.832Z"},
    "updatedAt":{"$date":"2021-04-28T21:18:41.832Z"},
    "__v":0,
    "avatar":"18756.png",
    "savedArticles":[
    "5eb91189c2de0f24fc1517db", // >> ObjectId of original
    "585ad7294a91aa0de83d8ac4"
    ]}
```

**My function:**

```
router.get('/savedItems/:id/', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  mongoose.model('Users').find({
    _id: id
   })
   .populate('savedArticles', 'title')
   .exec(function(err, results) {
       if (err) {
        console.log(err)
           return;
       }
       res.render('savedItems.ejs', { savedArticles: results, user: req.user })
       console.log( JSON.stringify(results))
   });
})
```

**Models:**

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var userSchema = new Schema({
// ...
    savedArticles:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Article' }]
},{ autoCreate: true})

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var articleSchema = new Schema({
    title:  { type: String, required: true },
 //...
  
})
const Users = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema)
const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema)
```

**In view:**

```
        <% for(i=0; i < savedArticles.length; i++) {%>
                <a href='#'><%= savedArticles[i].savedArticles %></a>
                <% } %>
```

**Output:**

```
    { _id: 5eb91189c2de0f24fc1517db, title: 'Gatsby' },  
{ _id: 585ad7294a91aa0de83d8ac4, title: 'Blade runner' }
```

**Output Update** with objects

```
{
  _id: ...,
  name: '',
  email: '',
  password: '....',
  savedArticles: [
    {
      _id: ...,
      title: '...',
      director: '...',
      year: '...'
    },
    {
     _id: ...,
      title: '...',
      director: '...',
      year: '...'
    }
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `populate`, then `mongoose` will based on the `_ids` that are stored in `savedArticles` array go and fetch from the `Articles` collection documents with those `_ids` and it will change `_ids` in `savedArticles` array with actual documents. So, when your frontend got the result, `savedArticles` array will be array of objects (documents from `Articles` collection) and not array of `_ids`.
Now you can iterate over that array and access specific field of each article, like: `savedArticles[0].title`.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation I was doubting since I have read more or less the same (for what I understand). savedArticles[0].title does not return anything it seems. Might be my mistake..

Comment: Try to `console.log()` the whole document that you got in the frontend, and check if it has `savedArticles` array of objects.

Comment: If you check your `output` that you posted in question, there are `title` fields.

Comment: I accept your answer however I can't get the output by your example. I am retreiving the entire object array in the console yes. by dong > .populate('savedArticles') However savedArticles[0].title does not return title of first item.. Looping over then in view like  savedArticles[i].key is also not working for me..

Comment: Can you `console.log()` the response from the server and add it to the question?

Comment: Added console log to my question

Comment: Well, all `articles` are there as you can see.  How you access them in the `html`? I see that you try to access `savedArticles` directly, but you have to access it as a property of the response object. Something like this: `response.savedArticles[0].title`.

Comment: <%= user.savedArticles[i]  %> returns agin only ID.. How does this correlate with my route?

Comment: Wait, if you fetch the response from server and articles are there when you console.log() the response in frontend, then issue is on the frontend. Can you add your frontend code that fetch data from backend.

Comment: right now this returns ID :  <% for(i=0; i < user.savedArticles.length; i++) { %>
                        <li>
                                <%= user.savedArticles[i]  %></li>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232359/discussion-between-timber535-and-nenad-milosavljevic).